# Value error with 'greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config.ModelComponentsParam'> for field SILVERKITE is not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, forecasting

I tried running the sample file 0100_simple_forecast.ipynb from Greykite but I could not get beyond the import statements.

I am using Greykite 0.5.0. on Python version_info(major=3, minor=11, micro=4, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

The error message starts with:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 12
10 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import ForecastConfig
11 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import MetadataParam
---> 12 from greykite.framework.templates.forecaster import Forecaster
13 from greykite.framework.templates.model_templates import ModelTemplateEnum
14 from greykite.framework.utils.result_summary import summarize_grid_search_results

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greykite/framework/templates/forecaster.py:40
38 from greykite.framework.pipeline.pipeline import forecast_pipeline
39 from greykite.framework.pipeline.utils import get_basic_pipeline
---> 40 from greykite.framework.templates.auto_model_template import get_auto_silverkite_model_template
41 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import ForecastConfig
42 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import forecast_config_from_dict

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greykite/framework/templates/auto_model_template.py:36
34 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import ForecastConfig
35 from greykite.framework.templates.forecast_config_defaults import ForecastConfigDefaults
---> 36 from greykite.framework.templates.model_templates import ModelTemplateEnum
37 from greykite.framework.templates.simple_silverkite_template_config import SILVERKITE_DAILY_90
38 from greykite.framework.templates.simple_silverkite_template_config import SILVERKITE_HOURLY_1

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greykite/framework/templates/model_templates.py:55
53 from greykite.framework.templates.auto_arima_template import AutoArimaTemplate
54 from greykite.framework.templates.lag_based_template import LagBasedTemplate
---> 55 from greykite.framework.templates.multistage_forecast_template import MultistageForecastTemplate
56 from greykite.framework.templates.prophet_template import ProphetTemplate
57 from greykite.framework.templates.silverkite_template import SilverkiteTemplate

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greykite/framework/templates/multistage_forecast_template.py:39
37 from greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config import MetadataParam
38 from greykite.framework.templates.base_template import BaseTemplate
---> 39 from greykite.framework.templates.multistage_forecast_template_config import MultistageForecastTemplateConfig
40 from greykite.framework.templates.multistage_forecast_template_config import MultistageForecastTemplateConstants
41 from greykite.sklearn.estimator.base_forecast_estimator import BaseForecastEstimator

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/greykite/framework/templates/multistage_forecast_template_config.py:44
42 from greykite.framework.templates.prophet_template import ProphetTemplate
43 from greykite.framework.templates.silverkite_template import SilverkiteTemplate
---> 44 from greykite.framework.templates.simple_silverkite_template import SimpleSilverkiteTemplate
45 from greykite.sklearn.estimator.lag_based_estimator import LagUnitEnum
48 @dataclass
49 class MultistageForecastTemplateConfig:

and ends with

File /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/dataclasses.py:815, in _get_field(cls, a_name, a_type, default_kw_only)
811 # For real fields, disallow mutable defaults.  Use unhashable as a proxy
812 # indicator for mutability.  Read the **hash** attribute from the class,
813 # not the instance.
814 if f._field_type is _FIELD and f.default.**class**.**hash** is None:
--> 815     raise ValueError(f'mutable default {type(f.default)} for field '
816                      f'{f.name} is not allowed: use default_factory')
818 return f

ValueError: mutable default <class 'greykite.framework.templates.autogen.forecast_config.ModelComponentsParam'> for field SILVERKITE is not allowed: use default_factory